# Does the blaze plan in google firebase will be sufficient for just calling a third party api atmost hundred times a day?

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Does the blaze plan in google firebase will not cost me anything for just calling a third party api atmost hundred times a day ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a product support (or customer service) issue.

Comment: The question is on topic, although vague. While superficially a product support question, it is related to differing developer features that are available at different pricing levels and at what point the user is likely to be charged for that. This is directly relevant to a developer determining if a development tool is appropriate for their development needs.

Answer (score 0):

There will probably not be any cost.  It depends on what your third party API calls are like.

Use the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) to calculate the cost yourself, given what you know about how it works.  There's a calculator for each paid product if you scroll down.  Only you can know all the details required to make an estimation.